# Extract Multiple text from a cell - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have a cell with a bunch of text in it. The information I need appears multiple times in the cell but always in different spots.

I have used this to extract the data (1 set) that I need. all the data I need starts with 00710

```
    =MID(L2,FIND("00710",L2),18)
```

This returns only one and I need to grab the rest if it appears in the cell. if can appear up to 5 times.

Comment: Not a programming question. better suited to SuperUser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this for the second occurence:

```
=MID(L2,FIND("α",SUBSTITUTE(L2,"00710","α",2)),18)
```

The `α` is just any character that doesn't appear in your string. You can change the 2 to 3, 4, or 5.